# UINavigationBar becomes black

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

First of all,  when i call presentViewController:navigationController it appears with normal green color navigation bar. But after animation is finished navigation bar becomes a little darker.

```
if(!userPageViewController)
    userPageViewController = [[UserPageViewController alloc]initWithUser:tempUser];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:userPageViewController];
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When i press the home button, navigation bar becomes black like on this image.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14066789/2013-12-04%2012.27.45.png

Top bar in xib file is set to Translucent Navigation Bar
Why it becomes black?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Личный кабинет";
    [myTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Закрыть" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backPressed:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btn;
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem  = nil;

    UIBarButtonItem *exitBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Выход" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(logOut:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = exitBtn;
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0f, 400.0f);

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
    {
        UIColor * barColor = [UIColor
                              colorWithRed:222.0/255.0
                              green:255.0/255.0
                              blue:229.0/255.0
                              alpha:1.0];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:barColor];
        UIColor * barTintColor = [UIColor
                                  colorWithRed:48.0/255.0
                                  green:140.0/255.0
                                  blue:76.0/255.0
                                  alpha:1.0];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:barTintColor];

        NSDictionary *navbarTitleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   barTintColor,UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                   [UIColor clearColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                   [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil];

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:navbarTitleTextAttributes];


    }
    else
    {
        UIColor * barColor = [UIColor
                              colorWithRed:73.0/255.0
                              green:208.0/255.0
                              blue:114.0/255.0
                              alpha:1.0];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:barColor];

    }

}
```

Comment: in your condition:

`if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)`,

`7` is not a float value, change it to `7.0`

Comment: Its still becomes black despite i changed translucent to opaque.
And change to float doesn't helps too

Comment: Did you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.
Fixed by turning off "Transcluent" checkbox in properties of Navigation Bar of my root Navigation Controller in Storyboard. 
You need to open left pane named "Document Outline" with small button in bottom left to find Navigation Bar.

Comment: Or if you created the `UINavigationController` in code, set its `navigationBar.translucent` to `NO`.

Comment: Try This Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654934/navigationbar-becomes-black-on-pop/38782691#38782691