# NavigationBar becomes black on pop

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, uinavigationbar

[image: First Image]

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISM7V.png)

[image: Second Image]

The issue is when i pop my controller the navigation bar becomes black which is very irritating. Help required!

Comment: i think you are hiding your navigation bar in some view controller

Comment: set your NavigationBar in viewWillAppear()

Comment: i got the solution as i was hiding the navigation bar in the controller to which the current controller was poping to

Answer (score 4):

When you Pop Your Screen You get back to Previous Screen.
In Preview screen you have to call this method in viewWillAppear.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

This will work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Swift version of @Nikunj answer.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```