# How to get rid of the navigation bar for one screen and show for the remaining

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to hide the navigation bar for the first view controller and show for the rest. In order to achieve this I wrote the following code :

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)

self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
{
super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

After writing this code it works fine, i.e this view controller does not show the navigation bar and the rest show as desired. But after writing this code another problem arise which is as follows:
[problem link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34654934/navigationbar-becomes-black-on-pop).
According to the solution given on the above link I need to remove the code:

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
}
```

Which brings me back to problem 1
Can anybody help to get rid of both issues?

Comment: you have so navigation to all otherview

Comment: self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden =false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead of `navigationBarHidden`:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
```

Comment: white pops up instead of black which is visible as well

Comment: @PersianBlue Updated my answer. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

In your `SecondViewController` add this code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```

Comment: you mean hide it on the first view controller and show it in the second ?

Comment: Nope. Still that black pop issue is there

Comment: the link i have given in the question has a screenshot. My screen looks exactly the same with same colors as well

Answer (score 0):

On the View you want to hide navigation bar. put this code.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true;

        print("Navgition bar hidden")

    }
```

On the next View, from where you want to show the navigation bar. put below code.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true;

            print("Navgition bar show")

        }
```